# How to filter data with checkbox categories

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core

How do I filter products based on which checkbox category is selected?
for example if "Pistols" checkbox is selected it only shows pistols.

view code:

```
<div style="background-color: #454545;">
    <ul class="category-ul">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="pistol" name="Pistols">
            <label for="pistol">Pistols</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="smg" name="SMGs">
            <label for="smg">SMGs</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rev" name="Revolvers">
            <label for="rev">Revolvers</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="shotgun" name="Shotguns">
            <label for="shotgun">Shotguns</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="assault" name="AssaultRifles">
            <label for="assault">Assault Rifles</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rifle" name="Rifles">
            <label for="rifle">Rifles</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

controller code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> weapons(decimal MinPrice, decimal    MaxPrice)
{

    var firearms = from s in _context.Firearm
                    select s;
    
    var max = firearms.Max(i => i.Price);
    
    MaxPrice = max;
    
    ViewData["MinimumPrice"] = MinPrice;
    
    ViewData["MaximumPrice"] = MaxPrice;
    
    ViewData["Maximum"] = MaxPrice;
    
    if (MinPrice > 0 || MaxPrice < max)
    {
        firearms = firearms.Where(s => s.Price > MinPrice
                                && s.Price < MaxPrice);
    }
    
    return View(await firearms.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
     
}
```

model code:

```
public class Firearm
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Caliber { get; set; }

    public string Barrel { get; set; }

    public string Magazine { get; set; }

    public string Sight { get; set; }

    public string? PicturePath { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a single category to be selected at a time (which I'm guessing might be the case because you said "checkbox category", not "checkbox categories"), then you need to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Next, you've set the `name` of each radio differently.  That means they won't interact and will be POSTed as separate fields.  What you want to do is give them all the same *name* (ex: "type"), but a different *value*.  When the form is submitted, the value of the field will then be the type selected.

You then bind that submitted value to a variable in your method definition:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> weapons(decimal MinPrice, decimal 
MaxPrice, string category)
```

Finally, add a condition in your LINQ to use the category.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a partial view.When selecting a checkbox,refresh the partial view which contains the filtered result in ajax:

view:

```
<div style="background-color: #454545;">
    <ul class="category-ul">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="pistol" name="type">
            <label for="pistol">Pistols</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="smg" name="type">
            <label for="smg">SMGs</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rev" name="type">
            <label for="rev">Revolvers</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="shotgun" name="type">
            <label for="shotgun">Shotguns</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="assault" name="type">
            <label for="assault">Assault Rifles</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rifle" name="type">
            <label for="rifle">Rifles</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    @Html.Partial("Test", value)
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $('input[name=type]').change(function(){
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            var selected=$('input[name=type]:checked').val();
            if (selected != undefined) { 
                $.ajax({
                    url: "weapons",
                    type: "POST",
                data: { type: selected },
                success: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data;
                }
            })
            }
             
        })
    </script>
}
```

action:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> weapons(string type)
{

    ...
    
    return PartialView("Test", filteredList);
     
}
```

Comment: ty. what do I write in the place of "value" in "@Html.Partial("Test", value)". I dont know much about jquery or partial view.

Comment: ` if "Pistols" checkbox is selected it only shows pistols.`You can use the pistols you want to show.And then show them in your partial view.